# return {xml_nodeset (0)}

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape summoner division regarding each season from lolking.net, using rvest package in R.

http://www.lolking.net/summoner/na/20130821/Wiggily#/profile

I am trying to use the following code to get the season number.

```
web.page.level <- read_html(url.level)
node <- html_nodes(web.page.level, css = '.unskew-text.ng-binding')
season <- html_text(node)
```

But I always get {xml_nodeset (0)}. There is no luck trying to use xpath too.
Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code? How could I get the content with in the html class '.unskew-text.ng-binding' ?

As dmi3kno suggested I am trying to use Rsekenium to scrape the page but there is still problem.

The html of the page for example,

```
<div class="unskew-text ng-binding">S4</div>
```

I would like to get the text 'S4'. I try to use both xpath and css.

```
elem <- remDr$findElement('xpath', "//div[@class='unskew-text ng-binding']")
elem <- remDr$findElement('css', "[class = 'unskew-text ng-binding']")
```

But I always get no such element error. Could any one tell me what I did wrong. Or is there any other way I can try?

Comment: It does not look like the page is static. If it is JS-generated page you might have better luck scraping it with {decapitated}, and/or {Rselenium}.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I still have problem with Rselenium. I have edited the question. Could you please provide more hint if you can?